# What is the difference between ubuntu-18.04-server and ubuntu-18.04-live-server?

Tags: server, system-installation, 18.04

On the [release page](http://releases.ubuntu.com/18.04/) there is a download link for `ubuntu-18.04-live-server-amd64.iso`, and on the [CD image page](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/releases/bionic/release/) there is a download link for `ubuntu-18.04-server-amd64.iso`. Before 18.04, there is only a server version. What is the difference between these 2 images?

Comment: even the gurus on a Ubuntu forum can't answer in what situations one should use "live" vs non-live, what hope is there for mere mortals like us ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It always helps to read the Release Notes.

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BionicBeaver/ReleaseNotes

> The next generation Subiquity server installer, brings the comfortable
>   live session and speedy install of Ubuntu Desktop to server users at
>   last.
>
> N.B., If you require LVM, RAID, multipath, vlans, bonds, or the
>   ability to re-using existing partitions, you will want to continue to
>   use the alternate installer

From Update to Release notes. But still some issues, see notes for full details.

> As of 18.04.1, the Subiquity server installer now supports LVM, RAID,
>   vlans, and bonds.

Comment: In fairness it's not very explanatory what a "comfortable live session" means. I just found out today about many issues using LVM with this version even though it supports LVM.
I haven't seen a proper user for this version yet and would recommend people to use the alternate version.

Comment: I would add that although the alternative installer allows setting up software raid, it does not seem to be as carefully maintained (there are other threads that attest that the download link on the page sometimes breaks, and I have had problems with verifying the integrity of files. I really wish the documentation would just be explicit that there is no good way to use any of the installers to set up UEFI boot + RAID1 with Ubuntu 18.04.2 server.

Answer (score 0):

There are some differences in the two installations, mainly in the packages installed. With the `Subiquity` installer `OpenSSH` , `cloud-init` , and some `Python 3` libraries are installed by default. Also, the resulting installation using the `Subiquity` installer takes up ~1.5GiB vs the ~1.7GiB of the traditional installer.

There are other differences but these stood out most to me.