# Why does 18.04 LVM default to 4GB despite more space available?

Tags: 18.04, system-installation, lvm

I've just noticed that a default install of Ubuntu 18.04 with LVM results in only 4GB of space allocated for the root partition, and the rest of the 500GB drive is left un-used. I find this goes against the principle of least surprise, I expected ubuntu to use the whole drive or to ask how much to use like 16.04 did.

Why wasn't it provisioned with more space?
Is this a bug? I've googled but couldn't find anything other than this: [Ubuntu Server 18.04 LVM out of space with improper default partitioning](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1106795/ubuntu-server-18-04-lvm-out-of-space-with-improper-default-partitioning)

However, that's a different question, as that question seeks to resolve the behavior by expanding the disk. I'm trying to determine whether the behavior I'm seeing is expected, a regression, or a bug.

It talks about how to fix it - and I have fixed it - but I don't understand why 18.04 defaults to such a small root partition with LVM?

Edit: I'm using the ubuntu-18.04.2-live-server-amd64 ISO.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The "Use the Entire Disk" option doesn't use LVM, I want to use LVM so that I can move the logical volume from one physical disk to another should I choose to down the road. In 16.04, if you selected the LVM option, it allowed you to choose how much space to give LVM, that option has vanished in 18.04 and instead it defaults to 4GB.

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate of the question you posted @K7AAY - that question asks how to fix it, I don't need to know how to fix it, I wish to know why it behaves this way and whether this is intentional or a regression.

Comment: @Nmath I appreciate your attempts to help here but I don't think you and I are on the same page here. I'm using the ubuntu-18.04.2-live-server-amd64 ISO and you appear to be using something else, which raises the question of whether the installer you're using behaves differently than mine, or perhaps if you're using 18.04 Desktop. I've just confirmed this behavior again, just now. I am 100% certain the installer I'm using behaves the way I described above.

Comment: https://www.redhat.com/mailman/listinfo/linux-lvm may have an answer for you.

Comment: "I'm using the ubuntu-18.04.2-live-server-amd64": edit this into your question.  I believe this may explain your issue: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1028580/what-is-the-difference-between-ubuntu-18-04-server-and-ubuntu-18-04-live-server.  I'd suggest using ubuntu-18.04.3-server-amd64.iso instead of "live-server": http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/releases/18.04/release/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mentioned using the live-server installer in the comments. LVM is not supported by the live-server installer. Here is a quote from the Ubuntu Documentation at https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/preparing-to-install.html

> Ubuntu Server 18.04 LTS introduces a new installer, the "live server" installer (sometimes called "Ubiquity for Servers" or simply "subiquity") which provides a more .user friendly and faster installation experience. At the time of writing it only supports amd64 processors and does not support LVM or RAID or other more sophisticated storage options, nor does it support reusing existing partitions on the disks of the system you are installing. It also requires access to the Ubuntu archive, possibly via a proxy. The previous, debian-installer based, installer is still available if these  restrictions mean you can't use the live server installer.

You're going to want to re-format your drive and use a different .iso file, as recommended in the comments