# About the new 20.04 network installer

Tags: server, partitioning, system-installation, mbr

It seems that with the release of **20.04**, the good old network installer has been thrown to the trash for some strange reason.

I tried to test the new one which is the **live-server** installer actually. Does this installer support **GPT** partitions exclusively? I cannot find an option to create **MBR** partitions anywhere and even if I try to install the new system on an **MBR** pre-partitioned disk, it doesn't allow me to use any of those partitions as root.

What's going on exactly? Has the support for **MBR** partitioning been dropped? If yes, what do we do on older systems that do not support UEFI at all?

Thank you.

Comment: Subiquity's been around since 18.04 (see, e.g., https://askubuntu.com/a/1028610/158442).

Comment: OK. What about MBR partitioning?

Comment: "Has the support for MBR partitioning been dropped?" No.

Comment: @Rinzwind, how do I manage MBR partitioning in Subiquity please?

Comment: Don't use efi to boot? AFAIK that is the only trigger. subiquity defaults to MBR when "new_iso/boot/grub/efi.img" is not present so maybe check if your iso has that?

Comment: @Rinzwind, does this mean that there are two different isos available for download or do I have to delete that file on mine?

Comment: 1 for each supported platform yes. When there is an EFI img on the disk you install the OS it will use EFI. If you BOOT with EFI (you pick that option in BIOS) it will also assume EFI. There is nothing where you can pick MBR. It is the not-picking of EFI that makes it MBR. When I make a mistake it is when I forgot to create an EFI on a new disk... so the other way round. I don't get the problem you have :(